# Question about Riemann Integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If $f \in R[a,b]$, then the function $F:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $F(x)= \int_a^x f$ is differentiable almost everywhere in $[a,b]$

---

I’m guessing this assertion is false because, if $f$ is the Weierstrass function, $f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \cos(3^n\pi x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ is known to be a function that is continuous everywhere, hence Riemann integrable, but $F’(x)$ is differentiable nowhere. Where is my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: You want to know about the differentiability of $F$, not $F'.$ In fact, if the statement wasn't true for a continuous function, we'd have a contradiction to the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus combined with the the criterion for Riemann integrability. Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, then it is continuous a.e. on $[a,b]$. Now $F$ is differentiable wherever $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is Riemann integrable, then it is continuous almost everywhere. The fundamental theorem of calculus guarantees that $F$ is differentiable almost everywhere on $(a,b),$ and hence on $[a,b].$

Comment: I know that if $f$ is continuous then f is Riemann integrable, I thought that the reciprocal was not true, why did you assert that?

Comment: I assumed since you used the terminology "almost everywhere" that you were familiar with Lebesgue's criterion, which states that a function on $[a,b]$ is Riemann integrable if and only if it is bounded and continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: Oh okay, I understood your argument. So you are saying that since $f$ is Riemann Integrable then by the Lebesgue criterion we know that $f$ is continuous almost everywhere which implies by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere in $[a,b]$?

Comment: Yup, that's it, except we get that $F$ is differentiable almost everywhere, not $f$ (I think that's what you meant, though)!

Comment: Oh yes, typo mistake. Thank you!